# Wordpress blog hacked

Tags: wordpress, hacking

My wordpress blog has been hacked.  Any page that I got to it shows the page html that hacker put in some where. I am not wordpress expert but it looks like hacker put the code somewhere (in database or file system).  Can someone point out where should I look at to remove that hacker code?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Wipe the filesystem, and upload a clean version, or restore from your backup.  Then apply patches.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Wordpress blogs are just that, blogs, not entire servers.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is with docs and resources from WordPress itself.

Work your way through these resources and follow all instructions to completely clean your site or you may be hacked again. See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)

Change all passwords. Scan your own PC. Use http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ before and after.

Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)